# Stop SQLAlchemy from updating rows that have already been pulled from the database

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm creating a simple notification system for a website.  The user's notifications are pulled from the database, marked as seen if they haven't been already, and then displayed to the user.  The ones that were unseen are displayed in bold.  Here's some of my code:

```
query = request.db.query(Notification)\
        .filter(Notification.user == request.user)
notifications = query.order_by(Notification.created_at.desc()).all()

print [ notif.seen for notif in notifications ] # [ False, False, False... ]
query.filter(Notification.seen == False).update({
    'seen': True
    })
request.db.commit()
print [ notif.seen for notif in notifications ] # [ True, True, True... ]
```

You'll notice from my print statements that `notifications` is modified when the `update` query is executed, despite already being pulled from the database with `.all()`.

I don't want this behavior.  I need to see what `notifications` **was**, not what it **is**, in order to bold the fields that have previously been unseen.

Looking through the docs, I thought setting the `synchronize_session` argument to `False` might work.

```
query.filter(Notification.seen == False).update({
    'seen': True
    }, False)
```

But unfortunately, it did not.

How might I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

synchronize_session=False as you are doing, but also you need to either not commit before looking at Notification, or turn expire_on_commit=False in your session.   The object is normally refreshed from the DB when first accessed after the commit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is worth it to do anything too tricky here like breaking synchronization or expunging objects from the session.  In this case it is probably better to save off a list of notifications that were unseen beforehand and then use that later in your application.

```
new_notifications = [notif for notif in notifications if not notif.seen]

# do the update stuff
pass

# later on
for notif in notifications:
    if notif in new_notifications:
        # This one is new, do some stuff
        pass
    else:
        # We already saw this notification, do some other stuff
        pass
```

If you need better performance store the ids in a dictionary and check against that:

```
new_notifications = dict([(notif.id, None) for notif in notifications if not notif.seen])

if notif.id in new_notifications:
    pass
```

One last solution would be to set a temporary property on the notifications like this(maybe in a more formal way with a class method or something):

```
for notif in notifications:
    notif.fresh = not notif.seen
```

Then your code depends on that fresh being set and uses it